# Derive a field from gradient expression that is linear in the field variable, $\textrm{grad}\,F \propto aF$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

Not a mathematician.
I have got a problem of finding by integration a field $F$ from the expression of its gradient.
It is a physical problem in continuous space $x,y$ and time $t$ and with real-valued smooth functions.

---

I first show the vanilla case I coped with; please do correct where applicable. The gradient relationship has the simple form
$$
\textrm{grad} F =a \{\cos (\omega t), \sin(\omega t)\}  
$$
I consider the differential form for the spatial variation:
$$
dF = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} dy
$$
Since the gradient components are independent of space, and of $F$, in my case the formula above becomes the relationship
$$
dF = a \cos(\omega t)\, dx + a \sin(\omega t)\,dy
$$
I integrate both sides along an arbitrary line on the plane $(x,y)$ and the result is
$$
F -F_0 = a \cos(\omega t)\, (x-x_0) + a \sin(\omega t)\,(y-y_0)
$$
where $F_0 = F(x_0,y_0)$, which I can set. The surface of $F$ is a rotating plane.

---

The case that I found difficult is when the gradient depends on $F$, say as simply as this form
$$
\textrm{grad} F =aF \{\cos (\omega t), \sin(\omega t)\}  
$$
The same differential form as above becomes
$$
dF = aF \cos(\omega t)\, dx + aF \sin(\omega t)\,dy
$$
If I tread the same steps as in the vanilla case above, I do not know how to derive a closed form for $F$ any longer.

Would someone please show and explain the way to derive $F$ from this second gradient expression?

Comment: I don't understand your first equation. $F$, hence its gradient, is a function of $x$ and $y$. How is $t$ related to $x,y$?

Comment: @TedShifrin The direction of the gradient changes in time. So the first solution, if correct, is a plane that rotates.

Comment: I see. So your gradient and differential are space only, with $t$ as a parameter. Assuming $F>0$, doing your first analysis with $\log F$ gives the second.

Answer (score 1):

1. Separate the variables in the expression of the differential:

$$\frac{dF}{F} = A \cos( \omega t) dx + A \sin(\omega t) dy $$

2. Integrate both sides over an arbitrary path:

$$\int \frac{dF}{F} = a \cos( \omega t) \int dx + a \sin(\omega t)\int dy $$

3. Set integration constant as $F_0=F(x_0,y_0)$ and solve the indefinite integral:

$$\ln\frac{F}{F_0} = a \cos( \omega t) (x - x_0) + a \sin(\omega t) (y-y_0)$$

4. Rearrange:
   $$F(x,y) = F_0 e^{a (x - x_0) \cos( \omega t)  + a (y-y_0) \sin(\omega t) } $$
   If you expand the exponential in a Taylor series around $x_0$, the first two terms of it return the expression for the simpler equation $\textrm{grad} F = a\{\cos(\omega t), \sin(\omega t)\}$.

With thanks to @TedSchifrin for the nudge.